# Rewrite trouble in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So I have a kind of strange trouble. I have a rewrite rule from

```
mysite.com/brand.php?brand=example&ref=ex1
```

to

```
mysite.com/brand/example/ex1
```

And I managed to do that, but there is also another problem: when you type this:

```
mysite.com/brand/example/ex1.html
```

or

```
mysite.com/brand/example/ex1.php
```

I get this:

```
mysite.com/brand/example/ex1?ref=ex1.php&brand=example
```

Can anyone tell why I get this redirect and how to get rid of it?

I tried this:

```
RedirectMatch   ^brand/([A-Za-z0-9-\.\_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\.\_]+)php$ /brand/$1/$2
```

or this:

```
RedirectMatch   ^brand/([A-Za-z0-9-\.\_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\.\_]+)\.php$ /brand/$1/$2
```

but it simply doesn't work.

Please, anyone help me!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `mod_rewrite` for this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/brand.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^brand=([^&]+&ref=(.+)$
RewriteRule .* /brand/%1/%2? [L,R]
```

The `RewriteRule` is applied only when both `RewriteCond` are valid. The first `RewriteCond` compares the request URL to be `/brand.php`, the second matches regular expression against the query string and stores the matches in `%1` and `%2` respectively.

In the `RewriteRule` is the URL rewritten using the matched parts from query string.